# Tomcat Cant Load Bean Class

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, startup, noclassdeffounderror

I have a tomcat 7 install and working application using Eclipse Kepler.  I moved the tomcat install to different folder and now the web app won't start up due to a missing class which is instantiated in a JSP file as an application level bean.

I edited the server definition (window | preference | server) to point to the new tomcat location.

I removed the server definition from eclipse and added a new one.  (this might have been a mistake)

I cleaned the tomcat work folder and rebuilt all projects

There are not any project errors

I am running local

Any ideas?

Comment: More investigation finds that the tomcat deployment does not include the included projects on the build path of the web app, \WEB-INF\classes.

Is there a project setting I need to change to have the classes deployed automatically when the app is run.  I have a hunch that folder may need to be changed

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.  The projects included on in the build path were not being deployed.  I had to go to the web app properties and Deployment Assembly to add the projects back in.